# Unit testing a monolithic main method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Having a *main* method and all the logic in it. How can I test (simulate) the input.txt in JUnit? Should I divide the code in smaller parts so I can call it by methods? A file input should look like below

```
/* 
   input.txt 
   add 2 
   add 2 
   apply 3 
   correct result 3 + 2 + 2 = 7
*/

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Operation> listOperations = new ArrayList<Operation>();
        int size = listOperations.size() - 1;
        int keepingCount = 0;

        try {
            File file = new File("input.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                String operationSign = parts[0];
                int numberFromLine = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                Operation operation = new Operation();
                operation.setCalculation(operationSign);
                operation.setNumber(numberFromLine);

                if (!operation.getCalculation().equals("apply")) {
                    listOperations.add(operation);
                } else {
                    listOperations.add(operation);
                    break;
                }
            }
            input.close();

            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                if (listOperations.get(x).calculation.equals("add")) {
                    if (keepingCount == 0) {
                        keepingCount = listOperations.get(x).number + listOperations.get(size).number;
                    } else {
                        keepingCount = listOperations.get(x).number + keepingCount;
                    }
                }
                if (listOperations.get(x).calculation.equals("multiply")) {
                    if (keepingCount == 0) {
                        keepingCount = listOperations.get(x).number * listOperations.get(size).number;
                    } else {
                        keepingCount = listOperations.get(x).number * keepingCount;
                    }
                }
                if (listOperations.get(x).calculation.equals("substract")) {
                    if (keepingCount == 0) {
                        keepingCount = listOperations.get(x).number - listOperations.get(size).number;
                    } else {
                        keepingCount = keepingCount - listOperations.get(x).number;
                    }
                }
                if (listOperations.get(x).calculation.equals("divide")) {
                    if (keepingCount == 0) {
                        keepingCount = listOperations.get(size).number / listOperations.get(x).number;
                    } else {
                        keepingCount = keepingCount / listOperations.get(x).number;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(keepingCount);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do we have `operator-precedence`?

Comment: Extract that part that performs file reading and returns `String` (or `List<String>`) and mock it.

Answer (score 1):

The whole logic is in your main so testing this is more like system testing (integration testing), and the best way is to write unit tests for each method and finally you may test main to make sure that all your methods are working fine together.

From [Stanford University Lecture Notes](http://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs190-spring15/lecture.php?topic=testing):

> "Unit tests:
>   Focused, low-level; 
>   test individual methods or pieces of methods.
>   Easier to ensure that each piece of code is tested
>   Easier to write and run
>   May not catch problems coming from interactions between different pieces of code
>   System tests (or integration tests): 
>   test the entire system working together.
>   Good for making sure that all of the pieces work together
>   Can generate more complex interactions between pieces
>   Harder to write and run."

Comment: I suggest you use a bigger text size.

Comment: Remember to include the source of all material you didn't write yourself (and ensure the author allows doing that). Also, rather than dump as text blob try to preserve the original formatting.

Comment: then this means should i divide the code in smaller parts?

Comment: yup, I think the best way is to divide the code into methods (maybe according to each operation) then you can write a unit test for each one of these methods